# How do I assign a name to a v8::Object so that scripts can access it?

Tags: v8, embedded-v8

I'm currently trying to add scripting functionality to my C++ application by using v8. The goal is to process some data in buffers with JS and then return the result. I think I can generate an `ArrayBuffer` by using New with an appropriate `BackingStore`. The result would be a Local. I would now like to run scripts via `v8::Script::Compile` and `v8::Script::Run`. What would be the name of the ArrayBuffer - or how can I assign it a name so that it's accessible in the script? Do I need to make it a `Global`if I need to run multiple scripts on the same `ArrayBuffer`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want scripts to be able to access, say, `my_array_buffer`, then you'll have to install the ArrayBuffer as a property on the global object. See https://v8.dev/docs/embed for an introduction to embedding V8, and the additional [examples](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/master/samples/) linked from there. In short, it'll boil down to something like:

```
global_object->Set(context, 
                   v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "my_array_buffer"), 
                   array_buffer);
```

You don't need to store the ArrayBuffer in a `Global` for this to work.